# How can I put number in x-axis of y-axis by myself?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
y <- c(2, 15, 8, 20,3,4, 7)
x <- c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
dat <-data.frame(x,y)

p<-ggplot(dat, aes(x,y, label=y))+ geom_line()+xlab("") + ylab("")+ 
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold',size=24),axis.text.x=     element_text(face='bold', size=20))+
scale_y_continuous("", limits=c(0,30))+xlab("")+theme_bw()+geom_text(vjust=-1, colour="purple")
```

After I run this code, only 2016, 2018, 2020 show in the x-axis. I want to write all of `x <- c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)` to the graph.

Which command should I use for that? In y-axis, I would like to show 0,5,10,15,20,25,20 rather than 0,10,20,30.

Comment: This is the `breaks` argument for `scale_x_continuous` or `scale_y_continuous`. Read the help for examples.

Comment: @user2225804 My guess is that the question could easily be answer by typing `?scale_y_continuous` in R. However, I also understand that `ggplot2` can be confusing to new users because its syntax differs greatly from base `R`'s plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon Gregor's comment, you need to use the `breaks` command inside of the `scale` functions, e.g., `scale_x_continuous`:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2015:2021)
```

So you plot command would be

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2015:2021) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20, by = 5))
```